# In IE10 I need double click on field to force it get focus in jquery dialog

Tags: javascript

In IE10 `onkeyup` doesn't work on element until it is double clicked (The element is in focus then only)

In FF and Chrome it works.

What is wrong and how can i fix this?

```
  <script>
   // this works
    document.getElementById('ContractNumber').onmousedown = function () {
        validateContractNumber(this);
    };

    // this not fired until i do double click
    document.getElementById('ContractNumber').onkeyup = function () {
        validateContractNumber(this);
    };
</script>

<style>
input[type=text]
{
   ....
   /*focus also doesn't work until double click this field*/
    &:focus
    {
        border: @Text-Focus;
        background-color: @Text-Focus-Back;
    }
}

</style>


<!--jquery dialog-->
<div id="dlgEditClient" style="display: none;">
    <div class="td editor-field left" title="Edit contract number for client">
        <input type="text" value="" name="ContractNumber" id="ContractNumber">
    </div>
    .............
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i have a nifty hack to get around this. But be warned, it's **NOT A DIRECT SOLUTION** .

So, in such cases, where you need double clicks, i prefer to induce a click pro grammatically.  In your case, i will try to see, if the browser is IE or not :

```
<%String browser = request.getHeader("User-Agent"); %>
function callDuringLoad()
{
<% if (browser.indexOf("MSIE") > 0) {
%>
document.getElementById('ContractNumber').fireEvent("onclick");
<%}
}

window.onload=callDuringLoad;
```

So , if the browser is IE , during load of the page, the function callDuringLoad will be called and it will fire , a click event on the id 'ContractNumber'. So , when the user manually clicks on that ID, it becomes a double click.

If `document.getElementById('ContractNumber').fireEvent("onclick");` does not work in IE 10, then you can use :

`document.getElementById('ContractNumber').click();`

**To detect IE 10 :** If you hate user agent sniffing and just want to detect IE 10 by javascript, then you can use this piece of code :

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") != -1){
    //you stuff here
}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer. In my case the problem was in using plugin qtip2, when i removed it all worked as expected